# Getting Time-Out Error While Posting Data

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

js.I am trying to create a file upload using node.js and mongodb.I am getting timeout error in posting data.The code that i use is:

```
app.post('/photos/new', function(req, res) {
  var photo = new Photo();
  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {
    if(err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      ins = fs.createReadStream(files.file.path);
      ous = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/static/uploads/photos/' + files.file.filename);
      util.pump(ins, ous, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          next(err);
        } else { photos.save({
           filename: files.file.filename,
                   file: files.file.path
                 }, function(error, docs) {
              res.redirect('/photos');
         });
        }
      });
      //console.log('\nUploaded %s to %s', files.photo.filename, files.photo.path);
      //res.send('Uploaded ' + files.photo.filename + ' to ' + files.photo.path);
    }
  });
});
```

I get the following error when i click on the submit button.

> Error: Timeout POST /photos/new
>       at Object._onTimeout (/home/nodeexmple/node_modules/connect-timeout/index.js:12:22)
>       at Timer.ontimeout (timers_uv.js:84:39)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this answer...

[Error: parser error, 0 of 4344 bytes parsed (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227020/error-parser-error-0-of-4344-bytes-parsed-node-js)

Also u can use req.clearTimeout() as suggested above by alessioalex.

I belive this part of your code is creating problems that u should avoid.

```
photos.save({
           filename: files.file.filename,
                   file: files.file.path
                 }, function(error, docs) {
              res.redirect('/photos');
         });
```

Instead use like this:

```
var post = new Post();
      post.filename=files.file.filename;
      post.file=files.file.path;
```

And then something like this:

```
post.save(function(err) {
                   if (err)
                return postCreationFailed();
                   req.flash('info', 'photos Succesfully Uploaded');
               res.redirect('were u want to redirect');
                });
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [connect-timeout](https://github.com/LearnBoost/connect-timeout) module so that is shows a message to your users in case the page takes more than X seconds to load (server-side).

It's obvious that the upload page might be taking more than that, so what you should do in your upload route is to clear the timeout like this:

```
app.post('/photos/new', function(req, res) {
  req.clearTimeout();
  ...
```

Read more about connect-timeout on its [github page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/connect-timeout).