# Error: parser error, 0 of 4344 bytes parsed (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use an upload program to upload my files. The code that I use is

```
app.post('/photos',loadUser, function(req, res) {
  var post = new Post();
  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
    } else {
      ins = fs.createReadStream(files.file.path);
      ous = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/uploads/photos/' + files.file.filename);
      post.filename=files.file.filename;
      post.file=files.file.path;
      util.pump(ins, ous, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          next(err);
        } else {
          post.save(function(err,docs) { 
        req.flash('info', 'information  Saved');
            res.redirect('/photos');
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

When I remove loadUser  method everything is working fine, but when I use the `loadUser` method it is giving me an error. The console information of the error is:

```
Error: parser error, 0 of 4344 bytes parsed
at IncomingForm.write (/home/darhamid/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:141:17)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/darhamid/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:91:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:67:17)
at HTTPParser.onBody (http.js:121:23)
at Socket.ondata (http.js:1349:22)
at TCP.onread (net_uv.js:312:27)
```

The error is caused only when i use loadUser function, if i remove the loadUser Funciton everything is working fine. 
I don't know the reason behind this and am stuck. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to perform database operation before everything, which is creating problems for you. Try the following code:

```
app.post('/potos', function(req, res, next) {
  //req.form.pause();
  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {
    if(err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      ins = fs.createReadStream(files.file.path);
      ous = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/uploads/photos/' + files.file.filename);
      var post = new Post();
      post.filename=files.file.filename;
      post.file=files.file.path;
      post.created_at = new Date();
      post.user_id = req.session.user_id;

      function postCreationFailed() {
        req.flash('error', 'Unable to Download ');
        res.render('photos/new', {
          locals: {
             post: new Post(),currentUser: req.session.user_id
          }
        });
      }

      util.pump(ins, ous, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          next(err);
        } else { 
                 console.log('\nuploaded %s to %s',  files.file.filename, files.file.path);
                 post.save(function(err) {
                   if (err)
                return postCreationFailed();
                   req.flash('info', 'photos Succesfully Uploaded');
               res.redirect('/user/photos/'+post.user_id);
                });
              }
      });
    }
  });
  req.form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected){
    var percent = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected * 100) | 0;
    process.stdout.write('Uploading: %' + percent + '\r');
  });

});
```

Good luck...

Answer (score 2):

See this github issue : https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/34

Comment: Tried to use pause() and resume() methods still getting the same error

Comment: I have tried this without using loadUser funciton and everything is working fine.The error seems to be because of using loadUser function which maintains the session of current user.Don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause for the problem is in this line:

request.setEncoding( "utf8" );